# What is the total underpayment penalty for not paying AMT immediately?

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options, alternative-minimum-tax

I exercised options (ISOs) in a startup so I'll have to pay the alternative minimum tax (AMT).  The amount is greater than $1000. (EDIT: the AMT will certainly be larger than my regular income)

What is the total amount I'll have to pay each month of this year for not having paid the tax immediately?

The interest rate [listed by the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/uac/interest-rates-remain-the-same-for-the-third-quarter-of-2016?_ga=1.27669692.1690081991.1481253075) seems to be 4% (for 2016) (so roughly 0.3% per month.  In addition to paying interest, is there also a penalty?

Comment: One source of confusion here: if you do not have sufficient during-the-year payments (which includes withholding) the additional amount you must pay is _computed_ as interest (balance due times number of days times rate) on form 2210, but _labelled_ a penalty (also form 1040 line 79). There is no _other_ penalty.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be overthinking this. In general, the alternative minimum tax (AMT) due (if any) is not due as of the date(s) when the events that triggered the AMT occurred and there is no need to worry about the interest
and penalties that you must pay for not paying the AMT **instantly**
when the triggering event(s) occurred. 
Indeed, the AMT is not determined until you prepare your income tax return for 2016 and, depending on what else is on your tax return, you may well
fill our Form 6251 and end up with the result that no AMT is due at all; your regular tax exceeds the AMT and so you just pay the regular tax.
But, even if Form 6251 shows that AMT is due, the amount just gets
added into "Total tax" shown on Line 63 of your Form 1040.

Now, after you compute the Total tax shown on Line 63 (which might or
might not include some AMT amounts), you add up your income tax withholding plus *timely* estimated tax payments made for 2016 (the fourth
quarter estimated tax payment is due January 17, 2017 instead of the usual January 15 because 15th is a Sunday and 16th is a Federal holiday).
If the sum total of income tax withheld and timely payments of estimated
tax is at least 90% of the current tax, or 100% of last year's tax (110% for high earners), there is no penalty or interest due and you can pay
Line 63 "Total Tax" minus Line 74 "Total payments" by April 15, 2017,
etc. But since this is doing things bass ackwards (you can't go back
in time to make estimated tax payments!), proactive folks
such as yourself, who *know* already that more tax is going to have
be paid than what has been withheld, can change your W-4
form for the rest of 2016 and have lots of income tax withholding
(enough to arrive at the 90% of current tax or 100% or 110% "safe harbor": the latter is easier because the numbers are known)
for the one or two paychecks still to come (check with payroll, though,
to see if they can process the paperwork in time). Extra tax
withholding is a particularly effective method because the total
tax *withholding* can be treated as *timely* payment of tax even if
most of withholding occurred late in the year. Another thing to keep
in mind: mutual funds distribute their dividends and capital gains in December (most will have posted their *estimated* distributions
by this time) and these will also affect the "Total tax" computations. If you don't have payroll withholding (or withholding from IRA
distributions or even Social Security benefits) to help, you should pay the 
amount that you need to arrive at a "safe harbor" via a 1040-ES estimated 
tax payment for the fourth quarter of 2016 (due by January 17, 2017),
and then pay the rest by April 15, 2017.
However, you will need to fill out Form 2210, including perhaps
the long part A1 if you wish to minimize the interest and penalties due
for not filing Form 1040-ES for earlier quarters. If you fill out the
short version of Form 2210 or ask the IRS to figure out the penalty
and send you a bill, you will likely pay a little more.

You will need to pay the rest of the tax due by April 15, 2017.

Comment: Thank you!  First of all, my AMT will be larger than my regular income (since I no longer have a job).  And just to clarify, the second paragraph gives advice for if I'm worried about interest and penalties, but the first paragraph says I don't need to be worried.  It sounds like if I have a large AMT, then I can just wait until filing my tax (in April 2017) to pay that, without penalties.  Correct?

Comment: @Zephyrus No, you can still owe penalties and interest. I have had to pay penalties and interest in years when I got a refund because although I had paid more than enough tax, I hadn't paid it in _timely_ fashion. See revised answer

Answer (score 0):

@Dilip
This is not right. If the amount you owe is because of AMT i.e. you paid your regular taxes on time, but not AMT, there is no penalty, because you would not know if you owe AMT until the end of the year

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/90005)

Comment: Dilip was right and you are wrong. In US except for the very simplest case -- a fixed salary/wage and no other income and little or no deductible expenses, no change in marital status or children and no other credits -- you actually don't know _either_ regular tax or AMT until the end of the year, and the 'penalty' (which actually is interest) does not distinguish them at all. But there is the safe-harbor of 100% (or 110%) of the _prior_ year tax, and everyone does know that.

Comment: This answer appears to be saying there are no penalties/interest, which is an attempt to answer the question (whether or not it's right).